# How to pass auth token to client in localStorage without ajax call from client

Tags: javascript, node.js

My nodejs app authenticate users through a 3rd party auth which redirects them to a specific page in my app. Using an ajax call I know how to send the auth info back to the client, but in this case the users ends up with a redirect on a secure page, without sending a manual ajax request.

I don't know how to store the token the user gets (serverside) in a localstorage, except from doing `response.send('<script>doLocalStorageStuffOnLoad</script>');` Is this really the way to go, it feels dirty :)

Comment: Do you need to redirect the user to a specific page? Couldn't this be done entirely on the client side and just returning the token as a response to an AJAX request?

Comment: *Note*: Storing auth tokens in local storage is bad practice: https://auth0.com/docs/security/store-tokens.

Comment: Thanks! I'm explicitly asking for a 'best way approach' for non-ajax call requests. I'm using a oauth2 3rd party website where users need to agree, so I need the redirect. 
I've indeed read a bit about localstorage not being safe, nevertheless handling clientside stuff when only get redirected (so without ajax call) still is something I need to get working.